# Вибирати та обирати - абсолютні синоніми чи ні?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, дієслова

Читаючи сайт [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53394/33370.html), я наткнувся на інформацію, що слова *"вибирати"* та *"обирати"* вживаються у різних значеннях: перше - коли ми говоримо про вибір якогось предмету, напрямку тощо, а друге стосується виборів депутатів, почесних членів тощо. Однак, перевіривши ці слова в Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови, я з'ясував, що як одне так і інше дієслово може мати обидва ці значення, отож виходить, що ці два дієслова таки абсолютні синоніми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В монографії Б.Антоненка-Давидовича є стаття щодо паронімів *обирати-вибирати*. Наведу цитату:

> ...слово *вибирати* стоїть там, де мовиться про напрям, матеріал, якусь річ тощо; воно може бути й синонімом дієслів витягати, діставати («От баба вибирає пиріжки та на стіл кладе, щоб прохололи». — О. Іваненко), відокремлювати («Кукіль з пшениці вибирати». — М. Номис), виймати («Бодай дідько очі вибрав!» — М. Номис). Там, де йдеться про вибори депутатів, почесних членів чи на якусь громадську посаду, як це бачимо в перших прикладах, слід послуговуватись дієсловом *обирати* (обібрати). Цим словом користуємося ще, коли мовиться про наречену, дружину («Та ви, певно, когось уже обрали собі, — так ви й кажіть». — Марко Вовчок), покликання, фах («Сам, добровільно, без чужого примусу, обібрав собі спеціальність». — А. Кримський) або влюблене місце («Сестри обрали затишне місце, вкрите густою травою і квітами». — Л. Смілянський).

Короткий підсумок: дієслово обирати стосується важливих справ, коли від рішення буде залежати майбутнє. Вибирати можна щось із ряду подібних, коли мова йде про повсякденні справи.

Цікаві уточнення щодо вибору слова в технічних текстах є [тут](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/241864.html):

> У технічному перекладі логічно казати "виберіть потрібні файли",
>   "виберіть кодування цієї сторінки", "виберіть адресата(ів)". До речі,
>   майже завжди коли мова йде про вибір кількох елементів - слово
>   "оберіть" стає недоречно пафосним.
>
> А коли обираємо щось одне й хоч трохи надовго - воно влучає саме в
>   ціль. "Оберіть теку встановлення", "Оберіть типове кодування",
>   "Оберіть безпеку та зручність нашого продукту!".